# smartos ubuntu image/vm login details

Tags: ubuntu, smartos

I am new to SmartOS.

I have created a vm on smart os using below json file

```
{
  "alias": "ubuntu-16-04",
  "hostname": "dns.example.com",
  "brand": "kvm",
  "vcpus": 1,
  "autoboot": true,
  "ram": 1024,
  "resolvers": [
        "10.0.0.2",
        "10.0.0.2"],
  "disks": [
   {
       "image_uuid": "643d5524-7eba-4a72-8fca-8dbb84d8d35d",
       "boot": true,
       "model": "virtio",
       "size": 10240
   }
   ],
   "nics": [
   {
       "interface": "net0",
       "nic_tag": "stub0",
       "model": "virtio",
       "ip": "192.168.0.53",
       "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
       "gateway": "192.168.0.1",
       "primary": true
   }
]
```

}

I can get to the console via vnc viewer but can't login as I don't know the default login credentials for ubuntu image.
Can anyone help me out please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW1zv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, you need to add public key via 
      "customer_metadata": { "root_authorized_keys": ... }
attribute to be able to login to KVM zone.

By the way, if your case is not very Linux-specific then you can try to use lx-branded ubuntu zone, since they are more simple to work with.